# Selecting radio button changes label text, when selecting new radio button, previously selected radio button label text needs to revert

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a page where people can choose ingredients for a recipe.

The page is split into 4 different kinds of ingredients, 2 of these ingredient groups you can only choose 1 ingredient of it's kind, so I thought it would make sense to use radio buttons rather than checkboxes, however the client wants the label to change from '+ Add to recipe' to '- Remove from recipe' when a radio input is selected. I can make that happen with the below code, but when they select something else in the group, the previously selected radio input label needs to revert to '+ Add to recipe'. That's what I'm struggling with.

Appreciate the help.

```js
$('input[name="s1-radio"]').on('change', function() {

 $(this).next().text(function(state, text){
       return text === '+ Add to recipe' ? '- Remove from recipe' : '+ Add to recipe';
        });
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="rk_button_container">
  <input type="radio" name="s1-radio" class="rk_button_input" value="11" data-variation-id="1" />
 <span class="rk_button">+ Add to recipe</span>
</label>

<label class="rk_button_container">
  <input type="radio" name="s1-radio" class="rk_button_input" value="13" data-variation-id="2" />
 <span class="rk_button">+ Add to recipe</span>
</label>

<label class="rk_button_container">
  <input type="radio" name="s1-radio" class="rk_button_input" value="9" data-variation-id="3" />
 <span class="rk_button">+ Add to recipe</span>
</label>
```

Comment: You mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3421ch9m/1/

Comment: That doesn't appear to be doing something different from the original, thanks though.

Hopefully this helps: 

No radio buttons selected.
I select the first radio button and the text changes to '- Remove from recipe' and the others still say '+ Add to recipe'

I select the second radio button, the first radio button text changes to '+ Add to recipe' and the second radio button text changes to '- Remove from recipe'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your jquery code to this:

```
$('input[name="s1-radio[]"]').on('change', function() {

$('.rk_button').text('- Remove from recipe' ? '+ Add to recipe' : '+ Add to recipe');
 $(this).next().text(function(state, text){
   return text === '+ Add to recipe' ? '- Remove from recipe' : '+ Add to recipe';
    });

});
```